# Using ESRI Dojo version for building web application

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

If I am using ESRI's JavaScript API for my application, then I cannot load a different version of Dojo other than the one shipped with ESRI. I have to rely on ESRI for Dojo. The map appears in only 3 pages. Do I have to use ESRI Dojo on the rest of the pages?

Does ESRI dojo load all components or only things specific to ESRI map? If I want to use other components, can I load those from ESRI?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using iFrames or childwindows and window.postMessage to communicate between your pages, I don't think you have to load ESRI's version of Dojo on the pages that don't use maps.  You could load whatever version of Dojo, or any other JavaScript library/framework of your choice.

Also, ESRI's JavaScript API comes with a full version of Dojo, including the Dojo, Dijit, and Dojox libraries. If you look at the bottom of their [What's New for version #.#](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/whats_new.html) page, they'll list the version of the Dojo library the API loads (currently [Dojo 1.8.3](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/1.8.html) for JSAPI v 3.6).